# Magento 2 - Orders with deleted products ProductRepositoryInterface The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again

Tags: magento2, product, orders, configurable-product, no-such-entity-exception

If I want to print my order using some PDF extension which uses the table from transactions emails, some invoices with deleted products are causing an error. As a result the table will be blank. However some orders with deleted products print just fine. I believe if it was a configurable product, the error occurs. But I might be wrong with that. If I disable the PDF extension and WeltPixel EnhancedEmail it prints just fine.

There is probably an error in my code, do you have an idea how I could fix it?

The error:

> main.CRITICAL: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. at /xxx/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:290)"} []

> #0 /.../generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository->get('2210107', false, NULL, false)

> #1 /.../app/code/WeltPixel/EnhancedEmail/Block/Order/Email/Items/Order/DefaultOrder.php(73): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor->get('2210107')

> #2 /.../app/code/WeltPixel/EnhancedEmail/Block/Order/Email/Items/Order/DefaultOrder.php(105): WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder->getProduct()

```
/**
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if ($this->getItem()->getProductOptionByCode('simple_sku')) {
            $product = $this->_productRepository->get($this->getItem()->getProductOptionByCode('simple_sku'));
            if($this->_productHasImage($product)) {
                return $product;
            } else {
                if ($this->getItem()->getProduct()) {
                    $configProduct = $this->_productRepository->get($this->getItem()->getProduct()->getSku());
                } else {
                    $configProduct = null;
                }

                return $configProduct;
            }
        } elseif($this->getItem()->getProductType() == 'grouped') {
            $groupedProduct = $this->_productRepository->get($this->getItem()->getSku());
            return $groupedProduct;

        } else {
            if ($this->getItem()->getProduct()) {
                $configProduct = $this->_productRepository->get($this->getItem()->getProduct()->getSku());
            } else {
                $configProduct = null;
            }

            return $configProduct;
        }
    }


     /**
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    public function getProductForThumbnail()
    {
        return $this->getProduct();
    }
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place `$this->_productRepository->get` calls in try/catch blocks, so you can capture that exception & let code flow continue

For instance

```
$configProduct = null;
try {
    $configProduct = $this->_productRepository->get($this->getItem()->getProduct()->getSku());
} catch (\Exception $e){
    ...
}
```